# Fifa 14 Game Play Issue

Tags: fifa-14

I want to know about the reflexes of Fifa 14 players. Compared to Fifa 13, it seems to be worse. The players reflexes feel very slow, and the defense is really bad.

I want to know if I'm the only one who is experiencing this or if this is a general game issue.  Can I make it better via a game setting? I haven't found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's nothing such as a low reflexes of the player, Fifa 14 is a step towards more real football were you have more control of your player. Yes, I do agree that it makes the game more difficult and doesn't magnetize the ball to player's leg, but this is how it is, as i said more real.

If you might have noticed a minor difference in sprinting between 13 and 14, the players in 14 never sprint instantaneously also when they sprint quite a distance it increses the distance between the player and the ball making it easy to tackle.

Moreover, speaking about the difficulty, a same team is more difficult to play in fifa 14 compared to Fifa 13. Also the professional & world class level of difficulty in Fifa 14 is quite more challenging than in Fifa 13. I'm not so sure of other levels, guess it's same there too.

All it needs is patience. Sometimes scoring no goals, getting aggitated and playing insanely might get you a goal in 13 but doesn't work with 14.

Talking about the defences, I too feel somethings are odd for Fifa 14 like you may not get your marker on the correct player when you press the player change button, when changing player is mannual or air balls only. And also the attacking players here have inherit sense to dodge the sliding tackle that you perform. Sometimes they may also dodge it in the attacking rectangle, save themselves a penelty and as well score which is quite surprising.

Well the thing with Fifa 14 is you need to be calm,  keep playing and don't give up on defeats because every defeat in Fifa 14 teaches you something new which is always usefull.

Answer (score 1):

GameFAQS had a thread on this. Lots of idiots over there, but if you wade through most of it they are saying that the ball is no longer magnetized to your feet. A lot of people are having trouble with this, including myself.

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/711401-fifa-14/67243709

I think it is something that we will just have to learn to play with. I have been trying to pass so I know I have time to settle it, vs. in 13 we could quickly play.

Best of luck!

Edit: Far better information on this thread: http://answers.ea.com/t5/FIFA-14/My-FIFA-14-players-and-AI-players-run-and-generally-react-slower/td-p/1902111